# How to setup PPPoE with OpenWrt

Tags: configuration, openwrt, router, ppp

Probably this is a simple question, but I can't find an answer...

I have an ADSL router (Dlink DSL-524T) which runs OpenWrt Backfire 10.03.1. It connects to the internet using PPPoA: this is my `/etc/config/network` file:

```
config 'interface' 'loopback'
        option 'ifname' 'lo'
        option 'proto' 'static'
        option 'ipaddr' '127.0.0.1'
        option 'netmask' '255.0.0.0'

config 'interface' 'lan'
        option 'type' 'bridge'
        option 'ifname' 'eth0 eth1'
        option 'proto' 'static'
        option 'netmask' '255.255.255.0'
        option 'nat' '1'
        option 'ipaddr' '192.168.1.6'

config 'atm-bridge'
        option 'unit' '0'
        option 'encaps' '11c'
        option 'vpi' '8'
        option 'vci' '35'

config 'interface' 'wan'
        option '_orig_ifname' 'nas0'
        option '_orig_bridge' 'false'
        option 'proto' 'pppoa'
        option 'encaps' 'vc'
        option 'atmdev' '0'
        option 'vci' '35'
        option 'vpi' '8'
        option 'username' 'x'
        option 'password' 'x'
```

I would like to switch to PPPoE, but I am not able to write a correct `network` file (and I can't find any *howto* on the internet). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Just follow instructions from OpenWrt WIKI page:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/internet.connection

And also this blog post is nice:
http://developwithguru.com/setup-and-use-pppoe-on-openwrt/

Edit : Note that the second link is dead. But you can find a cached copy at this address : https://web.archive.org/web/20150721030152/http://developwithguru.com/setup-and-use-pppoe-on-openwrt/

Comment: Please improve this answer by including actual instructions, not only links.

Answer (score 2):

```
config 'interface' 'loopback'
    option 'ifname' 'lo'
    option 'proto' 'static'
    option 'ipaddr' '127.0.0.1'
    option 'netmask' '255.0.0.0'

config 'interface' 'lan'
    option 'type' 'bridge'
    option 'ifname' 'eth0 eth1'
    option 'proto' 'static'
    option 'netmask' '255.255.255.0'
    option 'nat' '1'
    option 'ipaddr' '192.168.1.6'

config interface wan
    option ifname eth0
    option proto pppoe
    option username 'pppoe_username'
    option password 'pppoe_user_password'
```

Note: pppoe settings just need the above configuration, and after a  network restart/reload you see pppoe dialing in syslog and after successful connection , you get a new interface name by pppoe-wan or pppoe